# The registration and login pages do not see bootstrap.css, site.css etc (Blazor)

Tags: authentication, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

The login and register page with .net core authentication seem to be without css and bootstrap.

I get errors in console

```
failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () bootstrap.css
failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () site.js
failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () jquery.js
...etc
```

In Pages\Shared\ _Layout.cshtml

I see the following code

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/css/site.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous"
          asp-fallback-href="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
...
...

<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/Identity/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Identity/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/Identity/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-ZvpUoO/+PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn/6Z/hRTt8+pR6L4N2">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj">
    </script>
    <script src="~/Identity/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

But there is no lib or css folder in Identity folder.
Any idea about that?